# Secondary Block in Ruby Enumerable

Tags: ruby, lambda

I can't find what this is called to find out more about why it works and how it works, but we've found that you can do this:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name)
people = [Person.new('foo'), Person.new('bar')]
# => [#<struct Person name="foo">, #<struct Person name="bar">]
people.find { |person| person.name == 'baz' }
# => nil
people.find(->{ [] }) { |person| person.name == 'baz' }
# => []
```

I'd like to think it's something of a fallthrough block whenever something returns nil, but perhaps someone could shed some light on how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

> ## find(ifnone = nil) {| obj | block } → obj or nil
>
> ## find(ifnone = nil) → an_enumerator
>
> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. If no object matches, **calls ifnone and returns
>   its result when it is specified**, or returns nil otherwise.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's rather difficult to find that from a cursory skim over the docs, I've added a request for an example to be added for the ifnone so its' existence is more apparent to readers.